# Not able to run signed applet from ASP.net application. Getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, applet, code-signing, classnotfoundexception

Currently i am trying to update the certificate for an application

I have signed my applet program(Applet.jar) with code sign certificate. After that i have tried to run the app and getting the exception as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: imaging.ImageApplet.

**HTML code**

```html
<applet id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imageApplet" 
  name="imageApplet" 
  code="imaging.ImageApplet" 
  width="1000" 
  height="152" 
  mayscript="true"    
  class="applateBorder" 
  archive="applet.jar" 
  style="overflow: auto;">
</applet>
```

**Manifest code**

```
Application-name : Image app 
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Codebase:*
Permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Library: true
```

Both html and jar files are at same folder.

Part of Exception will be as follows with debug mode

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://hardscapeimagingsoftware.com/onlineimaging/imaging/ImageApplet.class,   version: null]
network: Connecting http://hardscapeimagingsoftware.com/onlineimaging/imaging/ImageApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://hardscapeimagingsoftware.com/onlineimaging/imaging/ImageApplet.class with cookie "countrytabs=1" 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: imaging.ImageApplet
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also do we need to resign the code for every year?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: *"Plz help to solve the issue. thanks"* Please spell words like 'please' fully.  This is not a text message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for the problem classNotFoundException. It was due to wrong ordering of folders during jar.

Apart from the every process was correct.